# ssh tunnel to container inside remote host

Tags: docker, docker-compose, apache-nifi, ssh-tunnel

I am running Nifi (A GUI based application) inside Docker container.
it was deployed using docker compose

compose:

```
    nifi:
        hostname: DWH_Nifi_prod
        container_name: nifi_container_persistent
        image: 'apache/nifi:1.19.0'  # latest image as of 2023-June.
        restart: on-failure
        user: root
        ports:
            - '8091:8080'
```

It is up and running.

Now as i want to open the UI, i need to open a ssh tunnel to it.

Earlier when i ran the application on the remote host (not on docker) I could easily establish the Tunnel using

```
ssh -L 8091:127.0.0.1:8091 root@remote_host.prod
```

Now i tried something similar

```
ssh -L 8080:127.0.0.1:8080 root@remote_host.prod
```

but could not succeed (error when opening UI : localhost sent an invalid response.)

Can someone please help me if there is anything extra to be taken care to establish a ssh tunnel for Remote hosts docker container  ?

Comment: Please let me know if any more details are needed in this question. I still could not find a way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I observed there is no difference in establishing ssh tunnel to container. its same as establishing to host machine.

`ssh -L 8091:127.0.0.1:8091 root@remote_host.prod` worked.

Earlier I could not access the page as my url is using https://, but i should use http:// only.

Answer (score 0):

SSH server is started on 22 port by default, so you I would try to expose it from docker container outside to the host machine, also you need to know the internal container's IP address to route the connection to. More details [here](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/how-to-ssh-into-docker-container).